# XML Soap body outside of envelope

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have looked at this for hours and really need another set of eyes. My envelope is closed and the body is not showing under it as a child but at a root. Here is the relevant code.

```
$XMLDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$XMLDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$XMLDoc->formatOutput = true;

// SOAP ENVELOPE ELEMENT AND ATTRIBUTES
$soap = $XMLDoc->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'soap12:Envelope');
$XMLDoc->appendChild($soap);

$soap->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:soap12', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
$soap->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$soap->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');


// SOAP BODY
$example_element = $XMLDoc->createElement('soap12:Body');
$rootNode = $soap->appendChild($example_element);
```

and here is the XML it is producing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
<soap12:Body>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, if you use `echo $XMLDoc->saveXML();` after the last line in the code, the Body is nested.  Also your output isn't XML as it would have 2 root nodes, which isn't valid.